# rails created_at value is null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timestamp, migration, created-at

```
<%= Case.all.count() %> cases
```

Giving me 300 cases

```
<% Case.order("id DESC").each do |c| %>
        <%= c.created_at %>
<% end %>
```

this giving me nothing

I added this migration so I can edit the created_at value

```
class AddTimestampsToCase < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :cases, :created_at, :datetime 
  end
end
```

but now I can't get the real created_at value. I want to restore the created_at value
Please advice! Thanks

Comment: what result are you hoping to get from `Case.all.group_by_year(:created_at).count()`. (Besides the fact that there's no group_by_year method, so it fails.) What count do you want?

Comment: @LesNightingill Hi, It should have all the cases created_at date

Comment: Are you trying to get a count by year? So how many were created in 2020 for example?

Comment: it should be around 100. few months ago I changed the timestamp for created_at so I can edit it but now I can't get created_at value unless i edit it and add it by myself

Comment: if you do `case = Case.create` from the rails console, and then inspect the value of `case` does it have a value for `created_at`?

Comment: @LesNightingill  #<Case id: nil, pt_first_name: nil, pt_last_name: nil, date_received: nil, due_date: nil, shade: nil, mould: nil, upper_lower: nil, user_id: nil, invoice_file_name: nil, invoice_content_type: nil, invoice_file_size: nil, invoice_updated_at: nil, implant_brand: nil, implant_quantity: nil, number: nil, finished: nil, ship: nil, outsourced: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, ready: nil, active: nil>

Comment: an instance of Case was not created when you did `Case.create`, b/c the id is nil. You need to find out why. Look in the development log.